# How to get integer row names of a data frame/matrix in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame A in which `max(A$user_id)=23000`. Also `typeof(A$user_id)=integer`. I made a data frame B with `rownames(B)=unique(A$user_id)` and `colnames(B)=unique(A$product_id)`. However, when I check `max(rownames(B))`, it comes out to be `999`. I did `row names(B)<-as.integer(rownames(B))`. But still, 
`max(rownames(B))=999`.What should I do to convert the rownames to integer? I want this because I want to fill up B according to rownames.

Answer (score 1):

rownames are characters

```
class(rownames(B))
```

therefore `max` is giving the last number alphabetically.

Depending on how you are filling your data frame you could either do `as.numeric(rownames(B))` each time you want to use the numbers, or make the first column of B be the integer numbers.

Comment: Whenever I want to do comparison of rownames(B), do i have to use as.numeric(rownames(B))?

Comment: Yes, use `max(as.integer(rownames(B))` or `max(as.numeric(rownames(B))` and things should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

`rownames` converts the `"row.names"` attribute to a character vector. To retrieve it as an integer, use `attr`.

```
max(attr(B, "row.names"))
```

From `?row.names`

> Row names are currently allowed to be integer or character, but for backwards compatibility (with R <= 2.4.0) row.names will always return a character vector. (Use attr(x, "row.names") if you need to retrieve an integer-valued set of row names.)